# Multiple lines php images

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to create an image that displays all the names from a database. So i got the array with all the names in it, but how can i make 1 image that displays all the names on seperate lines using PHP? And please provide an example. I've tried a lot, but they all didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/cfb6a

```
// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
$lines = 1;
for($i = 1;$i < 10; $i++){
   imagestring($im, 5, 5, $lines * 12, "Hello world $i!", $textcolor);
   $lines++;
}

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: What is it that makes a new line here?

Comment: @Thew: $lines * 10 - it just moves text a bit down (fourth parameter is Y coordinate

Answer (score 1):

It should look something along the lines of the following:

```
// $gd = <GD resource>
// $names = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');
$font_height = 6;
$colour = imagecolorallocate($gd, 0, 0, 0);
for($i = 0, $count = count($name); $i < $count; $i++)
{
   imagestring($gd, 4, 2, $i * $font_height, $names[$i], $colour);
}
```

Comment: What could i use for $gd? imagecreate?

Comment: @Thew: Yes, that would be a valid GD resource